# Can I use ObjectChangeListener to listen for changes on any object?

Tags: java, swing, jndi, javabeans

I've got an `Integer` called x; if it changes then i would like to update my table in a GUI. To listen to "x" I have tried

```
ChangeEvent y = new javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent(x);
```

and I implement `javax.naming.event.ObjectChangeListener`:

```
class HDIManagementView extends FrameView 
         implements ObjectChangeListener, ActionListener, TableModelListener  {
```

and I override the `objectChanged` method to update my table. Nothing happened

```
public void objectChanged(javax.naming.event.NamingEvent name){
//gets which status
    Object y=name.getChangeInfo();
    String m=y.toString();
    tableModel.setValueAt(y, 0, 0);

}`
```

if i change "x" then nothing changes in my table. What have I done wrong?

Second question is, x can only be called by value. i can only reach x from my database or my properties file. When database changes, x can't understand if it changes or not Even if listener listens. All i do is listen y which equals x. When x changes y doesn't understand because x is not calling by referens. What can i do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the question is **"no - you can't"** and **"JNDI and `javax.naming` is nothing to do with your problem"**

I think you may be confusing the Swing/JavaBeans listener framework with **JNDI**, the Java naming and Directory interface. An `ObjectChangeListener` is only useful for listening to objects which are bound and re-bound in a JNDI context. *You cannot use an ObjectChangeListener to listen for changes on an arbitrary object*

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.rebind("path/to/x", new Integer(4));
```

In order to do this, you need a JNDI implementation. In order to *listen* to the change, you listen on an `EventContext`:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
EventContext ec = (EventContext) ctx.lookup("");
ec.addNamingListener("path/to/x", myListener)
```

If you try this *it will fail because you have not defined a JNDI provider*. Typically these would be provided by an application-server vendor, e.g. IBM WebSphere or JBoss. The application server provides JNDI for applications to lookup resources like data sources, or configuration information.

**In order for you to do what you actually want**, you'll want to implement some class which wraps your integer and uses the *property-change* mechanism in Java:

```
public class MyInteger {
  private int x;
  private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  public void setX(int i) {
     int old = x;
     x = i;
     pcs.firePropertyChange("x", old, x); 
  }

  public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
      pcs.addListener("x", l);
  }
}
```

Then, this can be used by your code:

```
MyInteger i = new MyInteger(9);
i.addListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangedEvent e) {
      //implement to process the change - e.g. update your table
      Integer i = (Integer) e.getNewValue();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think i am confused too :) Actually, i have no idea what you are talking about. ALL i want is just to see if an Integer changed? So i wrote some article and http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeEvent.html . Maybe i am in the wrong way

Comment: See my updated answer - you just want a `PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: Do i have to use JNDI to understand when integer changes?

Comment: No - forget about JNDI - it is **nothing whatsoever** to do with your problem

Comment: My computer says something about your code. It says "can not find symbol pcs" :) you can fix it. and thanks. I'll try

Comment: I've made a small syntax error. It should be PropertyChangeSupport pcs