# Java - objectChanged does not trigger

Tags: java, listener, eventtrigger, changelistener

I have a java class named Project that implements `ObjectChangeListener`. I want the `objectChanged` method to trigger when the Projet object is modified (one of its attributes value changes). Here is my code :

```
public class Projet implements java.io.Serializable, ObjectChangeListener {
    (...)
    @Override
    public void objectChanged(NamingEvent evt) {
        m_Controleur.projetEstModifie();
    }

    @Override
    public void namingExceptionThrown(NamingExceptionEvent evt) {

    }
```

But `m_Controleur.projetEstModifie()` is never called when I modify the attributes of a Projet object (on runtime). Do I have to add anything else to the class ?

Comment: Not familiar with `ObjectChangeListener`, but are you using it in the [right context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346684/can-i-use-objectchangelistener-to-listen-for-changes-on-any-object)?

Comment: The way listeners work generally is that object X implements a listener interface, object Y adds object X as a listener, and then object Y fires events for object X to pick up. Simply implementing a listener interface is not going to do anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346684/can-i-use-objectchangelistener-to-listen-for-changes-on-any-object @An ObjectChangeListener is only useful for listening to objects which are bound and re-bound in a JNDI context. You cannot use an ObjectChangeListener to listen for changes on an arbitrary object@

Comment: Thank you all. I thought ObjectChangeListener was what I needed, but it is not. I will wrap my object as this post explains it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346684/can-i-use-objectchangelistener-to-listen-for-changes-on-any-object